# iOS 10 : MessagesViewController access currentUser from native app (Parse.com)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios10, imessage

I would like to extend my native app for Messages in iOS 10.

I succeed to display "Hello World" in Message app when I select my app, but I would like to display the username of the account connected on my app.

I'm using Parse.com, so I know the code `[PFUser currentUser].username`, but returns `null`. The username works on the native app (not extended for messages).

So how can I link the two apps, and access some values from the native app ?